# seaborn distplot of race times error: unsupported operand type datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime, seaborn

I'm trying to create a distplot of race times. My times look like this:

```
00:27:53
00:27:53
00:27:53
00:27:54
00:27:54
00:27:54
00:27:54
00:27:55
00:27:55
00:27:56
00:27:56
00:27:56
...
```

the type is `datetime.time`. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

what can I do?

Comment: I don't think This format is not supported by distplot, So you can change this to longtime format and then you can visualize the data.

Comment: You cannot plot datetime objects with distplot. See github. https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1059